# What are the types of DMRG?

Tags: reference-request, one-topic-per-answer, terminology, dmrg, computational-frameworks

The following questions have worked out very well  :

- [What are the types of Quantum Monte Carlo?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1594/5)
- [What are the types of SCF?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1568/5)
- [What are the types of MCSCF?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1566/5)
- [What are the types of ab initio Molecular Dynamics?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1523/5)
- [What are the types of pseudopotentials?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1521/5)
- [What are the types of DFT?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1513/5)
- [What are the types of charge analysis?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1439/5)
- [What are the types of bond orders?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/901/5)

In the same format, I am interested in a 2-3 paragraph explanation of what separates each "flavor" of DMRG from the others, and in which software each DMRG flavor is implemented. I know of the following types of DMRG, but if people know others they are welcome to add them!

- [**t-DMRG**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.10588) (time-adaptive DMRG, or time-dependent DMRG: [TD-DMRG](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.12044), or [Dynamical DMRG](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.11342))
- [**p-DMRG**](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.5031140) (stochastic perturbative DMRG)
- [**TMRG**](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0701243) (transfer matrix RG)
- [**SDMRG**](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.97.195125) (symmetrized DMRG)
- [**CTMRG**](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.1949) (corner transfer matrix RG)
- [**iDMRG**](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1739/5) (infinite DMRG)
- [**ED/DMRG**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.05956) (hybrid exact-diagonalization/DMRG)
- [**Thermal DMRG**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.10006)
- [**Zero-site DMRG**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.10880)
- [**DMRG-X**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.07721) (DMRG targeted for highly excited states)
- [**DMRG-isPT**](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jctc.6b00696) (DMRG with inner space perturbation theory)

Acronyms that signify the combining of ordinary DMRG with another method, such as [DMRG-TCC](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jctc.8b00960),  [DMRG-SCF](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.5642), [SA-DMRG-SCF](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jctc.9b00969), [DMRG-CASPT2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.05526), [DMRG-CASSCF](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.4976644), [DMRG-PDFT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.06273), [MPSPT](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.4895977) and DMRG-QUAPI are unnecessary for this question (though if there's interest, a different question could cover those, as well as techniques like spin-adapted DMRG).

Answer (score 5):

### p-DMRG

[Perturbatively corrected DMRG](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.07150) by [**Sheng Guo**](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=RjSgzhEAAAAJ&hl=en), [**Zhendong Li**](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=MYZZUJ0AAAAJ&hl=en), and [**Garnet Chan**](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=TDzdHZgAAAAJ&hl=en) (in 2018).

**Motivation:** DMRG scales poorly with respect to the number of basis functions. the above paper says that DMRG's cost is $\mathcal{O}\left(M^3D^3\right)$ for $M$ basis functions and a bond dimension of $D$, and that $D$ often has to scale as $\mathcal{O}\left(M\right)$, making the DMRG cost scale quite steeply with the number of basis functions: $\mathcal{O}\left(M^6\right)$.  *Basically:* DMRG is very powerful for studying [50 electrons with 50 basis functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.10307), but would require too mcuh RAM even for studying [6 electrons in 500 basis functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.13453). It is excellent for treating *static correlation* of highly multi-reference systems, but poor for treating the remaining *dynamic correlation*.

**Description:** Partition the Hamiltonian into $H_0+V$ where $H_0$ is solved  "exactly" with standard DMRG, and the resulting MPS $|\psi_0\rangle$ is used to treat $V$ perturbatively: but the partition is done such that $H_0$ requires a *much* smaller bond dimension $D_0$ than you would need if you were to treat the whole Hamiltonian with standard DMRG; *and* while treatment of $V$ requires a large bond dimension $D_1$, the treatment is done via minimization of a Hylerraas functional and a sum of MPSs, which is far less expensive than a standard DMRG treatment, and this allows $D_1$ to be roughly as big as the $D$ in standard DMRG would be if one were to try to treat the entire Hamiltonian with similar accuracy in comparison with p-DMRG. [Much thought went into how best to define $H_0$ in the first paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.07150), but a [second paper posted on arXiv 8 days later](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.09943) settled on an Epstein-Nesbet partitioning, and also introduced an even more efficient way to treat the perturbative correction by using a stochastic method.

**Cost:** The more efficient stochastic algorithm (2nd paper) has two cost contributions: $\mathcal{O} \left(M^3D_1^2D_0 \right)$ and $\mathcal{O} \left(N_s N^2 K^3 D_0^2 \right)$ for $N_s$ samples in the stochastic sampling.

**Implementations:** The two aforementioned papers don't mention any software packages in which the method is implemented, and I see no mention of it in the documentation for PySCF (of which all three of the authors of the aforementioned papers, are very involved). Since the method was introduced 2 years ago, it may be in early stages and only implemented in an in-house code by the original authors, though I would not be surprised if it were to be implemented in PySCF shortly.

**Remarks:** The original authors emphasize that p-DMRG is different from DMRG-CASPT2 or DMRG-NEVPT2 where there is a CAS/non-CAS partition rather than an Epstein-Nesbet partition. p-DMRG targets *quantitative* accuracy for systems with more basis functions than standard DMRG can handle, but far fewer basis functions than what one would have in a *qualitative* treatment of dynamic correlation in DMRG-CASPT2. Also, there is a parameter $\lambda$ which can be tuned for example to avoid intruder states in $|\psi_0\rangle$: They found $\lambda=1$ to be more prone to the intruder state problem, so they mainlused $\lambda=0$ and $\lambda=1/2$.